How to get an edit text box to get a predetermined input no matter what the user puts in?
In Android, I am trying to make a keyboard that automatically types a predetermined phrase no matter what the user inputs.
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-
12345678901234567890-

